# esp8266 arduino wifi connection memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am working on a hobby project which takes 3 different data from end points in JSON format and displays in LCD screen. I wrote a Arduino sketch here it is you can find it on my Github:

[esp8266 Arduino sketch](https://github.com/eldemcan/dublinbusiot/blob/master/client/client.ino)

I am using [TaskScheduler](https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler) library, LCD screen will update information every minute in weekends between 7:00 - 10:00 after that it will not make any request unless button is pushed. I am getting time using [NtpClient](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient). My problem is  a`ESP.getFreeHeap()` gets lower and lower whenever I do request and it never releases memory, even though I stop requesting after 10:00. Eventually after a day or two device run outs of memory and it freezes.

Where should I look, or how can I prevent a memory leak? I tried to restart esp board using `ESP.restart()` but it does not actually restart the device.

Comment: I see where memory is allocated in `createLcdMessages(...)`, but there does not appear to be any delete to release that memory later after use?

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look Paul, interesting point I did not focus on strings but apparently they cause memory issues. I tired to use free() method inside printLcdMessages method after but it crashes esp board. Do you know how can I free those strings ?

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Comment: You should not use free, since you used new. (new/delete ... new[]/delete[] ... malloc/free 'pairs' is how it should go) I was thinking that you could do `delete[] messages;` after line 256.

Comment: Thanks very much @PaulT. It seems leak has stoped now. I was not aware of this keyword since I don't use C++ frequently. Thanks very much again for taking your time to look into my code. I found a link maybe it will be useful for  someone else like me:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: Good, glad that helped! Know that this was technically _NOT_ strings causing memory issues, but rather, the dynamic memory management (that happened to be used for strings, in this particular case) was mishandled. Yes, I should have mentioned cplusplus.com, I like that site too. Glancing at the rest of the code yesterday, I did not see any other obvious memory-leak matters, but a minor improvement (or two) could be done.

Comment: @PaulT. Would you mind to tell me where should I focus for improvements ?

Comment: One is inside the function tryNetWorkConnectionNthTime().  Lines 104-106 could be into the else block after line 102. The current handling will still show a "retrying" message (though only once, because the loop will terminate) after the "connected" message from line 99.  Might be confusing output: connected followed by retrying ?

Comment: The other is to improve the handling at memory allocation. (line 273) At the cplusplus site, see their handling example when allocation fails. Add your print message should failure occur with "memory failed" (or whatever you prefer) to the if, and then your current lines 275-308 replaces the code in the else block. Along with this change, after line 255, add check that messages is NOT a nullptr before doing lines 256 and 257. Hope this makes sense?